# How to perform summation over specific columns of a table?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

Consider the following table:

```
fff[x_, y_, z_, k_] := 
 10^-9*NIntegrate[Exp[-(x/z) t^2 + y*t*k], {t, x^(1/9), 100}]
tabb = Flatten[
  ParallelTable[{x, y, z, k, fff[x, y, z,k]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0.5, 
    5.5, 1}, {z, 0.2, 2, 0.2}, {k, 0.2, 1, 0.2}], {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Is it possible, having `tabb`, to compute the average value of the fifth column for all possible values z, k **at fixed x, y** in a straightforward manner?

I made the following ugly code, but it seems that it is not optimized and works slowly. Also, it requires knowing all the possible values of x,y, which requires some manual extraction.

```
tabbxvalyval[xval_, yval_] := 
  Select[tabb, #[[1]] == xval && #[[2]] == yval &];
tabb1 = Flatten[Table[{xval, yval, 
   Sum[tabbxvalyval[xval, yval][[i]][[5]], {i, 1, 
      Length[tabbxvalyval[xval, yval]], 1}]/
    Length[tabbxvalyval[xval, yval]]}, {xval, 0, 1, 0.1}, {yval, 0.5, 
   5.5, 1}],{1,2}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not to flatten the table, since the relevant information is contained in its formatting and can be extracted by `Part` and `Total`.

```
T = ParallelTable[{x, y, z, k, fff[x, y, z, k]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0.5, 5.5, 1}, {z, 0.2, 2, 0.2}, {k, 0.2, 1, 0.2}];
fvalues = T[[All, All, All, All, 5]];
xy = T[[All, All, 1, 1, 1 ;; 2]];
averages = Total[fvalues, {3, 4}]/Times @@ Dimensions[fvalues][[{3, 4}]];
xyaverages = Join[xy, ArrayReshape[averages, Append[Dimensions[averages], 1]], 3];
```

The absolute error may seem to be large, but the relative error is as good as it can be:

```
Max[Abs[tabb1[[All, 3]]/Flatten[xyaverages, 1][[All, 3]] - 1]]
```

> 4.44089*10^-16

If you are given only the flattened list and if the list cannot be `ArrayReshape`d to the structured form (e.g., because the rows of `tabb` have been shuffled, you can `Nearest` and `SparseArray` to perform the lookup much more efficiently:

```
xy = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0.5, 5.5, 1}], 1];
A = SparseArray[
   Transpose[{Flatten[Nearest[xy -> "Index", tabb[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]], Range[Length[tabb]]}] -> 1.,
   {Length[xy], Length[tabb]}
   ];
tabb2 = Join[xy, Partition[A.tabb[[All, 5]]/Total[A, {2}], 1], 2];
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the problem is that I typically have only the flattened table. Another situation is even when the initial table does not have such a nice structure, and it is simpler to flatten it.

Comment: I see. See my edit for another way to do it.

Comment: Could you please tell me why `tabb[[All, 1 ;; 2]]` but not `tabb[[All, {1,2}]]`? The second option seems to work faster for some tables I've used, but maybe not in all cases?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) with [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html).

```
assoc =
  Query[
    GroupBy[#[[;; 2]] &]
    , Mean@#[[All, -1]] &
    ]@tabb;
Short@assoc
```

> ```
> <|{0., 0.5} -> 2.074*10^12, <<64>> , {1., 5.5} -> 0.00023595|>
> ```

This gives the result as an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) with the keys the x-y pairs.

```
assoc[{0., 0.5}]
```

> ```
> 2.074*10^12
> ```

However, this can be easily converted into a list of lists.

```
lst = Apply[Append] /@ Normal@assco;
Short@lst
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.5, 2.074*10^12}, <<64>> , {1., 5.5, 0.00023595}}
> ```

Hope this helps.